# I am unable to make a payment with trial amount as 0 using paypal.

Tags: paypal

I am able to subscribe for free trial period in paypal but unable to get any response from paypal in terms of return parameter so that I can update the same in my database.  Can anyone please help me out in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) to handle any database updates, email notifications, or anything else you might want to automate based on transactions with your PayPal account.

IPN will handle payments, subscription profiles created, profiles canceled, profiles expired, refunds, disputes, etc, so you can automate all sorts of things based on different types of transactions.

Comment: I am using IPN itself.  Once I make a payment there is no transaction taking place as total amount for transaction is $0 AUD.  So paypal is not sending me back any return string except an return url.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're doing.  Are you working with Standard Subscriptions, the Recurring Payments API, or what?  Either way, IPN is completely separate from all of that, and you would get 1 IPN when the profile is created, and then separate IPN's for payments associated with them.

Comment: I am using recurring payment API using Subscription button.  Let me clearly describe what I am upto. I want to set up an trial period for $0 and subscription should start from Sept 15 2014.  I am successfully able to subscribe for it and I can see in Merchant account regarding transaction also.  But when paypal auto re-directs  to our site it is not sending any return string so that my program can sense and do necessary post subscription operations in our DB.

Comment: Ok, you keep throwing me off.  "recurring payment API using subscription button" doesn't make sense.  You're either using one or the other.  Are you actually building an NVP or XML request and sending it within a PHP script or something similar via HTTP request over to PayPal?  Or are you just using a basic HTML subscription button?

Comment: I was able to crack this. I am able to get return parameters.  Thanks for your quick reply